# Does Google Compute Engine support .htaccess files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm attempting to clean some urls in a simple PHP application I have deployed on google cloud servers (Ubuntu). However, the redirect conditions I have written in a .htaccess file seemed to be ignored. I've went through Google's documentation and I haven't found a solution, I've gone through my .config files and ensured that mods_rewrite was enabled. I was thinking that because i'm on a shared server that the rules are being ignored. IF anyone has any suggestions or workarounds, please suggest.

Here is the .htaccess file for reference:

```
Options +MultiViews

#Remove php extension
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#Remove html extension

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 3):

at google cloud service you can install apache2 and enbale .htaccess on it :')

> Note to enable .Htaccess go to :  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

and search this line :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

change to :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: it's already enabled, also I think its discouraged to use the apache2.conf file as it makes it harder to update installs later, I believe its preferred to use /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf. But, i read that awhile ago, so I have check again.

Comment: @TerrellGilbert this sounds alike an `Ubuntu` specific comment. `Debian` is the default Linux image on `GCP`, while `CentOS` is also quite popular... which don't have that directory. and a `VM` equals a "root server", not a "shared hosting"... whatever is being configured globally, will be picked up by the virtual host configurations.

Comment: It is, sorry i'll specify  the distro in the question.

Comment: The solution above broke the site. Had to undo it.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours playing with the .config files, if you edit the virtual host settings in 000-default.conf  in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/ folder . I removed the Options Followsyslinks line. I don't know how this will effect security or performance, so I'll read up on that.

*Note that this for apache version 2.4.18